# Turn arraylist from string into arraylist

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, sharedpreferences

To store an arraylist on Android Studio using JSON it is turned into a string so when it is retrieved I need to convert it back to an arraylist. The arraylist contains objects. Or is there a way to store arraylists with shared preferences as an arraylist and not as a string.

```
SharedPreferences accountReader = getSharedPreferences("storedAccounts",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor accountEditor = getSharedPreferences("storedAccounts",0).edit();

ArrayList<userAccount> accountsList = new ArrayList<userAccount>();

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = accountReader.getString("accounts","");

if(json.isEmpty() == false){ 
   //repopulate accountsList with the stored values 
}

userAccount newEntry = new userAccount();
newEntry.id = id;
newEntry.username = username;
newEntry.password = password;
newEntry.url = url;
newEntry.note = note;

accountsList.add(newEntry);

Gson gsonTwo = new Gson();

String jsonTwo = gsonTwo.toJson(accountsList);
accountEditor.putString("accounts",jsonTwo);
accountEditor.apply();
accountEditor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(yourString.split(",")))
```